# Angular/Protractor Functions within tests are being called in the wrong order

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, angular, protractor

I am attempting to get the values of a column within a grid and compare the column with the same column after a sort button has been clicked. I have one function which gets the column's values, and a second function which I call after clicking the column header. The second function gets the new column order and compares it to the first function. For some reason my 'checkOrder' function is always being called as soon as the browser starts no matter where it is positioned within the testcase and therefore returning undefined. This is resulting in the second function always confirming that the order of the column has in fact changed from undefined to whatever the column order was when the second function was called. (Who would have guessed) :)
Here is a test suite:

```
it('should sort auditing log grid by time column', () => {
    page.navigateTo();
    sleep();
    checkOrder('1');
    page.getTimeColumn().click();
    checkOrderHasNotChanged('1');
    checkOrder('1');
    page.getTimeColumn().click();
    checkOrderHasNotChanged('1');
    checkOrder('1');
    page.getTimeColumn().click().then(function() {
        console.log(checkOrder('1')
    )});
    expect(checkOrderHasNotChanged('1'));
});
```

Here are the functions:

```
    export function checkOrderHasChanged(column: string) {
        var unSorted = [];
        var ele = element.all(by.css('kendo-grid-list tr td:nth-of-type(' + column + ')'));
        ele.map(function (eachValue) {
            return eachValue.getText().then(function (unSorted) {
                return unSorted;
            });
        })
        .then(function (unSorted) {
            var sorted = unSorted.slice();
            sorted = sorted.sort();
            expect(checkOrder(column)).not.toEqual(unSorted.reverse());
        });
    }

    export function checkOrder(column: string) {
        var unSorted = [];
        var ele = element.all(by.css('kendo-grid-list tr td:nth-of-type(' + column + ')'));
        ele.map(function (eachValue) {
            return eachValue.getText().then(function (unSorted) {
                return unSorted;
            })
        })
    }
```

Thanks for any suggestions/explanations you may have!

Comment: You missed a `return` ahead `ele.map(function (eachValue) ` in checkOrder(), and some wrong place in your code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You missed a return ahead ele.map(function (eachValue) in checkOrder(), and some wrong place in your code.  I did some changes upon your code, please try it.

```
it('should sort auditing log grid by time column', () => {
    page.navigateTo();
    sleep();
    let beforeVals = readColumnValue('1');
    page.getTimeColumn().click();
    let afterVals = readColumnValue('1');
    checkOrderHasNotChanged(beforeVals, afterVals);
}); 

export function checkOrderHasChanged(beforeSortVals, afterSortVals) {
    Promise.all([
        beforeSortVals,
        afterSortVals
    ])
    .then(function (data) {
        let beforeVals = data[0];
        let afterVals = data[1];
        // do assertion
        //expect(beforeVals).not.toEqual(afterVals);
    });
}

export function readColumnValue(column: string) {
    let eles = element.all(by.css('kendo-grid-list tr td:nth-of-type(' + column + ')'));

    return eles.map(function (eachValue) {
        return eachValue.getText().then(function(text) {
            return text.trim();
        });
    });
}
```